# Get WiFi SSID upon connection

Tags: wifi, systemd, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

When I'm connected to my metered mobile phone's wifi hotspot I would like to run a script to do things like kill the torrent downloader, stop syncthing, etc.

When I'm back on my unmetered home wifi hotspot, I'd like to automatically start those things up again.

When I connect to a new unknown hotspot, I'd like to ask the user whether it is metered or unmetered.

---

I would like my script to be called like:

```
wifi-connect.sh <SSID>
```

How do I setup this trigger?

I'm on a `systemd` system (Manjaro, based on Arch Linux).

... Or is there a tool out there which already does what I'm after?

Comment: What OS does your phone use? NetworkManager detects metered connections appropriately with some versions of Android, so it will flag your connection as metered when you’re using your phone’s hotspot, and unmetered when you’re using your wi-fi router at home. (That doesn’t answer your general question, I know.)

Comment: Android 6.0.1, kernel 3.10.103 - and yes, this is supported. Thanks for a good nudge in the direction of a solution.

Comment: In asking this question, I was looking for a UUID for a WiFi network. I thought it could be the ESSID, but it seems that [an ESSID doesn't exist per se](https://www.cwnp.com/forums/posts?postNum=294480) and is simply an SSID shared by all BSS in the ESS. So it appears there isn't a WiFi ESS UUID.

Comment: What about the MAC address of the AP? That should be a fairly good proxy for a unique id for wi-fi networks.

Comment: The MAC of a single AP (BSS) is part of the universally unique BSSID [if I understand it correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Basic_service_set_identifier_.28BSSID.29). However, if more than one AP is used due to range (an ESS) then the identifier is the non-unique SSID... I guess I could assume that all metered networks are only a single AP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've moved countries and the motivation behind the question is no longer there.

However, some pointers for when it becomes pertinent again:

- [Run script upon network connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/14139/47870)
- Get SSID: `iwgetid --raw wlp2s0`
- `nmcli -t -f GENERAL.METERED dev show wlp2s0 | grep -q yes && echo "Connection is metered"`
- [Change metered status on the device's active connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364927/143394)
- The connection may need to be disconnected and reconnected for the device to set itself metered, so checking on the connection will be more accurate.