# NetworkManager: Set current connection of device as metered

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

With NetworkManager, how do I set the currently connected connection on my device (say `wlp2s0`) as metered?

How do I unset it in such a way that guessing of the metered/unmetered state will still occur?

Note: some hotspots will be metered (eg my phone) and some won't (eg home), so setting this on the device isn't what I'm after.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I really hope that this isn't the best answer: it seems convoluted in the simple case, and even more so if allowing for a binary SSID. Anyways, here goes:

**Get device's current connection**

```
nmcli -t -f GENERAL.CONNECTION --mode tabular device show $DEVICE | head -n1
```

`-t` is required as there is a space appended at the end otherwise (!?).

**Show current metered status**

```
nmcli -f connection.metered connection show $CONNECTION
```

Where `$CONNECTION` is the string returned by the previous command.

**Change metered status**

The valid statuses are `yes`, `no`, and `unknown`. `unknown` is the default, which will do the guessing based on things like DHCP option `ANDROID_METERED`  [(reference)](https://www.spinics.net/lists/fedora-desktop/msg14161.html).

Example: set $CONNECTION to be metered:

```
nmcli connection modify $CONNECTION connection.metered yes
```

---

**Allowing for binary SSIDs**

To do this "right" (allowing for 32 arbitrary octets in the SSID), you'll need to use the *device*'s `GENERAL.CON-PATH`:

```
nmcli -t -f GENERAL.CON-PATH --mode tabular device show DEVICE | tail -n1
```

This will return a string like: `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/39`

Then use this path to get *connection*'s `GENERAL.CON-PATH`. **NB:** this has a *different* value (a device's `CON-PATH` == connection's `GENERAL.DBUS-PATH`)

```
nmcli -t -f GENERAL.CON-PATH -m tabular connection show apath /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/39
```

This will return a string like: `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5` (note no `ActiveConnection`). This can be then used to modify the connection:

```
nmcli connection modify /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/<NUMBER> connection.metered <VALUE>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `head`, not `tail`, in the first snippet?

Comment: @Luciano, no because the device is listed on the first line.

Comment: I'm not experienced with nm - do I have to do this every time I join the network, or does this go into the saved settings of a given connection?

Answer (score 1):

An adaptation of @TomHale-s answer to just get the **active** connection status:

```
CONNECTION_UUID=$(nmcli -t -m multiline -f UUID connection show --active | head -n1 | cut -c 6- )

METERED=$(nmcli -t -m multiline -f connection.metered connection show "$CONNECTION_UUID" | cut -c 20-)

# possible values are "yes", "no", "unknown":
echo "$METERED"
```